# Button inside div that was made inside jquery not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have jquery code:

```
$("#forcedcancel").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#forceDialog").remove();

    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight/3) - 20;  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth/2) - 200; 

    var forcedialog = "";
    forcedialog += '<div id="forceDialog" style="margin:'+dialogTop+'px 0 0 '+dialogLeft+'px;z-index:10;position:absolute;border: 1px #000 solid ;padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;background-color:#fff">';
    forcedialog += '<h3>Reason for force cancelling the lesson</h3>';
    forcedialog += '<p><textarea id="forcereason" style="width:475px;height:121px"></textarea><p>';
    forcedialog += '<button id="submitforce" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button><button id="cancelforce" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>'
    forcedialog += '</div>';

    $('body').prepend(forcedialog);
});

$("#forceDialog").on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
    alert("HERE");
    $("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```

When I am clicking the button with id="forcedcancel", the custom dialog with id="forceDialog" is showing up. But when I click the button Cancel inside that div, alert("HERE") is not firing. I'm too tired to notice the error I guess. :(

Comment: HTML is in var forcedialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a delegated handler, however the primary selector needs to be an element which is present at page load, which `#forceDialog` is not. The closest static element appears to be `body`, so try this:

```
$("body").on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
    alert("HERE");
    $("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```

Also, you may want to consider using `class` attributes instead of `id` as your current code will leave you with multiple elements with the same `id` after several clicks of the button.

Comment: You are brilliant. Thank you so much sir! May i ask what delegated handler means? I want to avoid it in the future. :)

Comment: @Taiga no problem, glad to help :) a delegated handler means that the event is attached to an element which does not directly fire the event itself. In the example I wrote, the event is attached to `body`, but is fired by `#cancelForce`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$(document).on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
    alert("HERE");
    $("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using event delegation, the element(`#forceDialog`) to which you are trying to add the handler is also created dynamically... so your click handler does not get registered.

When you use event delegation the element to which the handler is attached to(element used in $(...)) must exists in the dom when the code is executed... in this case since the `forceDialog` element is added to the `body`, you can bind the handler to `document` or to `'body'` elements

```
$(document).on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
    alert("HERE");
    $("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Very well explained. Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

find it in whole document

```
$("body").on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
alert("HERE");
$("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the handler to the body and the check the clicked dynamically added element selector.

Read deeply: http://api.jquery.com/on/

So try using:

```
$("body").on("click", "#cancelforce", function(){
    alert("HERE");
    $("#forceDialog").hide("slow");
});
```